# Click events for push notifications don't work as expected in Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: angular, windows, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

Using a service worker, the screen transition is performed by the click event of the push notification with the following code.
Screen transition is possible in Chrome on Mac, but screen transition is not possible in Chrome on Windows 10.
Is there any solution?

```
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clientList) {
            focusWindow(event);
            if (clientList.length > 0) {
                return clientList[0].focus();
            }
            return self.clients.openWindow('../hoge/fuga');
        })
        
    );
});
```

Comment: The same is true for the Chromium version of Edge.

Supplement.
I am testing a service worker using a self-signed certificate and launching the browser with the certificate error disabled.

Comment: It is a supplement again.
I don't know if it's related, but I don't use FCM etc., but I use the web-push library to make push notifications.